# Spring Security static resources and webjars issue (Spring Boot 2)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm struggling with Spring Security getting static resources from folder and from webjars. Structure of the project is like this:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src/main/resources
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── loginStyle.css
│   │   ├── js
│   │   └── images
│   │       ├── myLogo.svg
```

This is my web config:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class AdherenceWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**", "/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/webjars/", "/resources/").resourceChain(false);
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/views/", ".jsp");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        // this will map uri to jsp view directly without a controller
        registry.addViewController("/adherence/login").setViewName("loginView");
    }
}
```

Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AdherenceWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/adherence/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

`loginView.jsp`:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport"
 content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="src/main/resources/static/favicon.ico" rel="icon"
 type="image/x-icon">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/loginStyle.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<title>BARMER Adherence Tool</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <form class="form-signin">
    <h3 class="form-signin-heading">
     <img src="/images/myLogo.svg" alt="Barmer_Logo" />
     <br />
     <b>Adherence Tool</b>
    </h3>
    <span>${message}</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="u_name"/>
    <br />
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="u_pass"/>
    <span>${error}</span>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-cstyle"
     name="Submit" value="Login" type="Submit">Login</button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/css/loginStyle.css] in 
DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-10-13 12:52:05.507  WARN 796 --- [nio-8088-exec-6] 
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request 
with URI [/images/myLogo.svg] in DispatcherServlet with name 
'dispatcherServlet'
```

and 404 for every `js`, `css` and `svg`.

All these resources were loaded correctly before I used Spring Security. I am using **Spring Boot 2.0.4**.

**===========================UPDATE-1=======================================**
I have some success. I am now able to load resources from the webjars but unfortunately still problems with my own resources (HTTP status code 302). Changes in web config:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**", "/resources/**")
    .addResourceLocations("/webjars/", "/resources/")
    .resourceChain(false).addResolver(new WebJarsResourceResolver());
    WebMvcConfigurer.super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
}
```

Changes in loginView.jsp:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/loginStyle.css" />
...
<h3 ...>
    <img src="/static/images/myLogo.svg" />
... />
```

The [new result are shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxlMq.png). Changing the path to e.g. /css/loginStyle.css results in 404. I also added my [project-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TM4f.png)

**===========================UPDATE-2=======================================**

Thanks to @Pasha Gharibi

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**", "/static/**")
.addResourceLocations("/webjars/", "classpath:/static/")
.resourceChain(false).addResolver(new WebJarsResourceResolver());
```

This did finally the trick for me. Now also the 302 status-codes for my self-hosted files are gone.

Comment: You are accessing your CSS with `/css/loginStyle.css`, but your web configurations adds a mapping for `addResourceHandler("/webjars/**", "/resources/**")`. That shouldn't work with or without Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

Request trys to get loginStyle.css file and have not grant.
You should add permision to your css folder, So replace this line :

```
.antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/resources/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
```

and the same for other stuff

Comment: That is what OP already does, see his Spring Security configuration. However, the missing permission should result in a 403 not in a 404.

Comment: You are right! Maybe Path is not correct, I mean .addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/static/")

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add webjars locator in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    <version>0.30</version>
</dependency>
```